# Painted skim coat is failing

Tags: drywall, painting, primer

See final edit at bottom for resolution/causation

Not-so-recent leak finally being patched out has continued to expose Glidden paints peeling in random places.

This house was *covered* in wall paper. When we bought it I spent a full month removing all remaining wall paper, sponging down the walls to get glue/sizing, and then cleaning the walls thoroughly. No problems with any paint there.

I'm guessing that the Previous Owner (PO) either hired someone to rip it down or did it themselves, didn't remove the sizing, and instead skim-coated with generic wall compound. Either way, it's coming off and the paint is ripping off in pieces. I can't tell if they even primed, to be honest.

I can not afford to 'deal with this' now. I'm guessing the stand by of 'sand it until the compound comes off'.

What other solutions might be possible that you could offer as suggestions?

Thanks kindly. Frustrating day.

Edit: I spent some time staring at it and thinking like the lazy PO. And then I took some measurements. And then I really looked at the wall.

I'm guessing 3 things happened.

1. They replaced part of the wall board at some point, prior to to wall paper. They used green board (waterproof).
2. They used pre-made mud that had either been thinned or something added that broke the bonding- I can keep rubbing the material and it falls apart. Unlike the mix, it's not strong.
3. The 2nd outlet is installed in a new work box.
4. there is a bad seam at 4' from a window (right by the casing).
5. I see yellow mesh tape

So... a very sharp spackle knife at an edge with a 45 degree 'slice' let me get off most of the paint down to the mud. The mud is scraped or wiped off, as much as possible. The paint does not appear to have been primed, or it was a paint/primer combo (useless crap).

The board is broken at the edge of the counter, saying they've never mudded or taped it to the lower drywall. I can also detect wall paper below it. Something to fix later.

After scraping the wall for for a couple of hours on and off (this is 4'x3' area!) I'm putting a light skim coat of 90 minute over the bad areas after scuffing. This I'll sand flat. I can't fix all of it but I can at least prime this to make it look somewhat presentable to get the kitchen back in order.

No, homedepot, you can't help and people can't do it.

Final Edit:
A disconnected drain forced the issue.

Removal of the cabinets and trim did indeed indicate there was wallpaper in the room- and that they never bothered to remove the sizing.
PO/or Lazy Contractor simply ripped down the drywall and then skim-coated readymade compound over the surface- then painted the room (no primer/sealer).
The only solution has been to knife the paint with an angled putty knife until it stops coming up, 20 minute mud over that surface to smooth it, then prime with a high adhesion primer (to hopefully hold the rest of the paint in place).

Comment: If leak and peeling paint in same area, might need remove and replace instead of sanding.

Comment: Are you sure they didn't skim coat over the wall paper or sometimes wallpaper?    Do you have pics?

Comment: @DMoore politely they probably did. I do find wall paper stuck under parts- they may very well have not pulled it all up. There are huge chunks of 'painted' wall where you can see sand paper and air bubbles still present under.

Comment: @crip659 Leak is independent and in a different area... peeling paint is not limited to this one area (other parts of kitchen, etc). Very good thought though- when I bought it initially and not knowing how much work properly removing wall paper was ... I probably would have put 3/8ths over it all.

Comment: Painting I don't mind, but all the cleaning, washing, patching to do for good paint job is another thing, so I keep putting off painting.

Comment: I'd suggest that "living with peeling paint until you decide to fix it properly" is probably not only your best option, but your only option. If the subsurface isn't good, no paint will stick for long. Painting over a poor subsurface will just be a waste of money, whether it's the cheapest Walmart paint or the best stuff you can get at the paint store.

Comment: If you can not afford to deal with it now, then what exactly is your question?

Comment: Dealing with all of the issues discovered would entail removing all cabinets, molding, etc. Probably cutting out drywall too (due to box placement issues and mix/match of green/regular). Issue was originally as to what would cause paint to peel and if there were any other remediation techniques beside 'rip it all out' that may be effective.